# splitting a text file in particular row and save the output

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop

hii experts i have a long text file that contain data as below

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

i want to split the file at particular column index and paste the splitted output side by side.so my expected output would be

```
1  5
2  6
3  7
4
```

can anybody suggest a solution in python .Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your input is stored in a list called `x` and you want to split at index `idx`

```
import numpy as np

# Split into two lists
x1, x2 = x[:idx], x[idx:]

# Get their lengths and determine maximum length
l1, l2 = len(x1), len(x2)
max_l = max(l1, l2)

# Lists have to be of equal length. Fill with empty strings
x1 += [''] * (max_l - l1)
x2 += [''] * (max_l - l2)

# Combine lists again
y = np.dstack([x1, x2])[0]
```

For your example, try to run it with

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
idx = 4
```

The result is

```
[['0', '5'], ['1', '6'], ['2', '7'],  ['3', ''],  ['4', '']]
```

You can print it for example via

```
print('\n'.join([' '.join(y_) for y_ in y]))
```

But also a for loop over the entries is possible.
You can save your output via:

```
np.savetxt('out.dat', y, fmt='%s')
```

I'm sure there are easier ways to do this, but this one seems to be nice to understand.

Comment: can u please suggest how to save it to text file again

Comment: it prints nice output

Comment: can u please suggest how to save it

Comment: @glkshu I added it, please check it :)

Comment: can u please suggest how to save output if i use print('\n'.join([' '.join(y_) for y_ in y])) for saving output.....i am getting error ValueError: Expected 1D or 2D array, got 0D array instead

Comment: Have you tried np.savetxt('out.dat', y, fmt='%s')? How does your y look like?

Answer (score 0):

Read the file and read line by line until you got the last line
now findout number of lines
if the number of lines are even then we can distribute 50% on each left and right
otherwise only half on left half-1 on left while printing

filepath = 'data.txt'

data=[]

with open(filepath) as fp:

line = fp.readline()

while line:

```
    data.append(line.split("\n")[0])

    line = fp.readline()
```

print(data)

if(len(data)%2==0):

```
half_len=int(len(data)/2)
```

else:

```
half_len=int(len(data)/2)+1
```

for i in range(half_len):

```
    if(i < half_len-1):

        print(data[i],data[i+half_len])
```

if(len(data)%2==1):

```
print(data[i])
```

else:

```
print(data[i],data[i+half_len])
```